# Validating a Varimax implementation?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I'm writing an implementation of factor analysis and I'm having trouble convincing myself (or even better, proving) that my varimax implementation is correct. What's the best way to prove that a Varimax implementation is working properly? I can imagine two different ways; does anyone know where I can find the following:

1. *Known good data sets.* A few "known good" data sets would be a great way to prove that my implementation is working right.
2. *Reference implementation.* A reference implementation (in any language is fine, but ideally Python or Java) would be useful because then I could just generate "known good" data sets myself. I have access to SPSS, but I can't figure out how to get SPSS to just give me a Varimax rotation of a certain data set, and I'd like to isolate the Varimax transformation from other computations.

All of this is more complicated if the Varimax mapping is not one-to-one. (That is, if each unique input to Varimax has only one correct output.) If Varimax is one-to-one, then if the output of my implementation differs from the output specified by one of the methods above, then I know it's wrong. If Varimax is *not* one-to-one, then I can conclude that my implementation is not the same, but I can't necessarily conclude that it's wrong. Does anyone know if Varimax has only one correct output for each unique, valid input?

Thanks for your help, guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my Varimax implementation whipped into shape. Here's what I did:

1. I found the discussion of SPSS' implementation of Varimax in [the v19 algorithms guide](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/support/Stats/Docs/19.0/Client/User_Manuals/English/IBM_SPSS_Statistics_19_Algorithms.pdf) very useful (linked from [the v19 documentation page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27022445))
2. I validated my unrotated solution against SPSS's unrotated solution, and then fiddled with my implementation until my rotated solution matches SPSS's rotated solution. This worked well because by checking the unrotated solution first, I was able to prove that any difference in the rotated solution was due to the Varimax implementation and no other part of the implementation. This would have been very hard to do without SPSS's documentation of the Varimax implementation, but with it the process only took about an hour.

Comment: Would you be willing to share the implementation?

Comment: Very willing, but unfortunately not able. The implementation belongs to my employer.

Comment: Gotcha. Did you ever come across other reference implementations or cleanly TeX'd up algorithms for fitting varimax besides the SPSS one?

Comment: I did not, unfortunately. However, I did find the SPSS docs very useful, for whatever that's worth!